# CI Build SSIS solution with 71 projects

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, ssis-2017

We have ssis_EDW solution developed in Visual Studio 2017 (Target SQL Server 2014,2016) having 71 SSIS projects in it. We have Azure DevOps Build Pipeline which is used to build the solution on Azure. Here, we have used Devenv.exe to build the .sln file and publishes the artifacts. It usually takes 7 mins to complete the Build. This has been running quite well for us over the time.

However, when we tried to add 72nd project to this solution file, the Build pipeline is not creating artifacts for it as soon as we add any new project. The Build pipeline run completes within just 2 minutes and does not create/publish the artifacts. We even monitored the Memory and CPU utilization at the time of Build to make sure CPU & Memory (RAM) is not peaked and it just under 50%. So, system configuration is not the issue (Self hosted agent).

Could someone please help here to let us know if there is any limitation on number of projects in single Visual Studio Solution file?

**Update**
DevOps Logs:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is any hard limitation on the number of projects in a single solution file and if there is the limit is well above 71. From experience, solutions with over 100 projects often have noticeable performance issues when being loaded and parsed. But they do run, You are under 100 projects. I would say that the issue you are seeing is not about a limitation with the solution file.

Comment: I agree with you @JonathanDodds that there is no limit on no. of projects. The DevOps logs does not offer any other clues except the 71 project build takes ~7 mins to finish vs problematic build (after adding 72nd project) takes ~2 mins.

Comment: Some steps you may have already tried but I'll offer here anyway: Does the behavior reproduce in a local build or only in a pipeline build? Can the solution be built with `msbuild` instead of `devenv`? (`devenv` invokes `msbuild` to perform the build.)

Comment: This behavior is observed only in Azure pipeline build, on local env it works fine. I can give a try for msbuild (haven't done this earlier).

Comment: Hi @JonathanDodds - I've added DevOps logs, please check if this gives any clues.

Comment: When I tried MsBuild, it failed. Per documentation, You can only build MSBuild based projects using msbuild. This integration services project types is still a non-MSBuild based visual studio project type and thus only builds using devenv.exe /Build / devenv.com.

Comment: Ah. The SSIS projects are not MSBuild projects. Are there resources that are shared across the projects? It may help to know if the project itself is an issue or if the order of projects is an issue. If the 'problem' project is in a solution of its own, does it build in the pipeline? If you change the build order of projects within the solution, does the problem change? (The project dependency settings in the solution will change the build order.)

Comment: @JonathanDodds - there is no dependency as such between projects. The build runs fine on the Self-hosted Agent machine as well. Its just that it succeeds on Azure Pipelines, but does not create artifacts for all projects.

Comment: The log shows an error - Exception Oxc0020001. It sounds like you are saying that the builds errors and fails but reports that it succeeded.

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening. The Azure Pipeline shows Build is successful. However, it does not create artifacts.